# Google Sign-In using Firebase in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-signin

***Note the question might be long because of the need for explanation otherwise it might be very vague and lead to same old answers.***

I am having problem in creating a `Google Sign-In` page in `React Native` using ***firebase***. Based on **firebase** documentation:

> With the updates in the 3.1.0 SDK, almost all of the JavaScript SDK’s
>   functionality should now work smoothly in React Native. But there are
>   a couple caveats:
>
> - "Headful" auth methods such as signInWithPopup(), signInWithRedirect(), linkWithPopup(), and linkWithRedirect() do not
>     work in React Native (or Cordova, for that matter). You can still sign
>     in or link with a federated provider by using `signInWithCredential()`
>     with an OAuth token from your provider of choice.

which means I ***cannot*** use following code in my **React Native** project:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {

  // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
  // ...

}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
  // ...
});
```

Then with some googling and searching over dozens of stackoverflow, I found following way to use use **Google SignIn** using ***Firebase API***
in **React Native** project as:

```
const provider = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
const credential = provider.credential(token);

  firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('SUCCESS', data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('ERROR', error)
    });
```

Now in **just above code**, you might have noticed **token** in following line:

> const credential = provider.credential(**token**);

So based on ***firebase*** documentation, **token** is obtained as follows:

```
// `googleUser` from the onsuccess Google Sign In callback.
var token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
```

So my question is how do I obtain that **token** using GoogleUser object or whatever it is in **React Native?** Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume you've added `GoogleSignin` to your project. If not, you can find a pretty good instruction [here](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin)

The callback that Google provides has an item, called `idToken`, which can be used to login via google into your firebase. Once you have returned that object from `Google Signin`, EG

```
  GoogleSignin.signIn()
        .then((user) => { this.loginWithGoogle(user) });
```

You can simply use this `user` object's `idToken` as a credential,

```
loginWithGoogle = (user) => {
    var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(user.idToken);
```

and then log into firebase using that credential

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).then(u => {
    //blah blah bleep
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer but can their be any API that google provides which can be directly used instead of using GoogleSignin? Plus I found lots of errors while implementing GoogleSignin

Comment: Probably is, but ive found GoogleSignin to be a really great solution. Was a pain to setup the first time, but as long as you follow the instructions i linked exactly its fairly straight forward